# HTML(5) and CSS(3) Standard library / API?

Tags: html, css

I'm totally new in HTML and Im wondering if there is a generally approved standard library / API for HTML+HTML5 and CSS+CSS3 just like that one for Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ with all the available syntax?

Comment: Well, no... they're not programming languages so they don't really have APIs or standard libraries. (Unless you're looking for DOM/CSSOM which are APIs for different things altogether.) They *have* language specifications, if that's what you're looking for, but CSS3 is a sprawling multitude of different specifications which will overwhelm a beginner very quickly.

Comment: "with all the available syntax" — This suggests you are confusing an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) with *documentation* for an API. (Requests for off-site resources are off-topic for Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most official reference you will find for HTML is on w3 but it's honestly not that good. I can't even find the document for CSS.

[HTML Reference on w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)

I highly recommend using the documentation on MDN instead.

[HTML docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)

[CSS docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: Though unofficial, many developers now swear by the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: The HTML Reference on W3 doc linked is over 5 years out of date.

Comment: I replaced it with a more recent version from 2014. I can't seem to find a more recent version from the w3c.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use those sites as a note or a small reference :

- [WebCodeScool](http://webcodetools.com/) (HTML5 / CSS3)
- [CSS4](http://css4.rocks/selectors-level-4/) (pseudo selectors)
- [sarasoueidan](https://sarasoueidan.com/articles/) (SVG / Animation ...)

Answer (score -2):

you can find a guide here:

- HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
- CSS3: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Thank I know these pages. But is there a generally approved API? Maybe from the founders of HTML?